# Why cant i start the python programm from my .NET MAUI methon?

Tags: c#, .net, file, error-handling, maui

When starting the process, the exception allways tells me that he cant find the main.py file or that it doesnt exsiist.

The file structure looks someting like this (just for reference):

- PictureRecognition (c# file)
- ai_model

  - main.py
  - blueberry.jpg
- ...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlindSpot
{
    public class PictureRecognition
    {
        public static async Task<string> ScanPicture()
        {
            string aiModelDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "ai_model");
            string pythonScript = Path.Combine(aiModelDirectory, "main.py");
            string pictureParameter = Path.Combine(aiModelDirectory, "blueberry.jpg");

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "main.py",
                Arguments = $"\"{pythonScript}\" \"{pictureParameter}\"",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WorkingDirectory = aiModelDirectory
            };

            using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
            {
                try
                {
                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                    if (process.ExitCode == 0)
                    {
                        return "Success: " + output;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "Error: " + output;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Error: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Already tried to change the working directoires or use the absolute path to call the python file, nothing worked.

Comment: what is the build action for the python files?  Have you verified that the directory path you are building is correct?